# How to pass variable to add_settings_section() callback?

Tags: options, api, settings-api

I am attempting to automate, as much as possible, the Settings API function calls for each setting in a Plugin. Looping through the options array, and outputting `add_settings_section()` and `add_settings_field()` is simple enough:

`add_settings_section()`:

```
$oenology_hooks_tabs = oenology_hooks_get_settings_page_tabs();
foreach ( $oenology_hooks_tabs as $tab ) {
    $tabname = $tab['name'];
    $tabtitle = $tab['title'];
    $tabsections = $tab['sections'];
    foreach ( $tabsections as $section ) {
        $sectionname = $section['name'];
        $sectiontitle = $section['title'];
        $sectiondescription = $section['description'];
        // Add settings section
        add_settings_section(
            'oenology_hooks_' . $sectionname . '_section',
            $sectiontitle,
            'oenology_hooks_' . $sectionname . '_text',
            'oenology_hooks_' . $tabname . '_tab'
        );
    }
}
```

And `add_settings_field():

```
global $oenology_hooks;
$oenology_hooks = oenology_hooks_get_hooks();

foreach ( $oenology_hooks as $hook ) {
    $hookname = $hook['name'];
    $hooktitle = $hook['title'];
    $hooktab = $hook['tab'];
    $hooksection = $hook['section'];
    add_settings_field(
        'oenology_hooks_' . $hookname,
        $hooktitle,
        'oenology_hooks_setting_callback',
        'oenology_hooks_' . $hooktab . '_tab',
        'oenology_hooks_' . $hooksection . '_section',
        $hook
    );
}
```

With `add_settings_field()`, I can easily write a generic callback, by passing the `$hook` variable to the callback, as the fifth parameter in the function call:

```
function oenology_hooks_setting_callback( $hook ) {
    $oenology_hooks_options = get_option( 'plugin_oenology_hooks_settings' ); 
    $hookname = $hook['name'];
    $hooktitle = $hook['title'];
    $hookdescription = $hook['description'];
    $hooktype = $hook['type'];
    $hooktab = $hook['tab'];
    $hooksection = $hook['section'];
    $inputvalue = $hookname . '_hide';
    $inputname = 'plugin_oenology_hooks_settings[' . $inputvalue . ']';
    $textareaname = 'plugin_oenology_hooks_settings[' . $hookname . ']';
    $textareavalue = $oenology_hooks_options[$hookname];
    if ( 'Filter' == $hooktype ) {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $inputname; ?>" value="<?php echo $inputvalue;?>" <?php checked( true == $oenology_hooks_options[$inputvalue]  ); ?> />
        <span>Hide <?php echo $hooktitle; ?> content?</span><br />
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <span class="description"><?php echo $hooktype; ?> Hook: <?php echo $hookdescription; ?></span><br />
    <textarea name="<?php echo $textareaname; ?>" cols="80" rows="3" ><?php 
        echo esc_textarea( $textareavalue ); 
    ?></textarea>
    <?php 
}
```

However, it appears that `add_settings_section()` does not have an analogous `$args` parameter; thus, I cannot use the same method to pass the `$section` variable to the callback.

**Thus, my question: is there any way to pass a variable to the `add_settings_section()` callback, or some other way to create a callback analogous to what I'm doing for `add_settings_field()`?**

EDIT:

@Bainternet nailed it! Here's my working code:

```
/**
 * Callback for add_settings_section()
 * 
 * Generic callback to output the section text
 * for each Plugin settings section. 
 * 
 * @param   array   $section_passed Array passed from add_settings_section()
 */
function oenology_hooks_sections_callback( $section_passed ) {
    global $oenology_hooks_tabs;
    $oenology_hooks_tabs = oenology_hooks_get_settings_page_tabs();
    foreach ( $oenology_hooks_tabs as $tab ) {
        $tabname = $tab['name'];
        $tabsections = $tab['sections'];
        foreach ( $tabsections as $section ) {
            $sectionname = $section['name'];
            $sectiondescription = $section['description'];
            $section_callback_id = 'oenology_hooks_' . $sectionname . '_section';
            if ( $section_callback_id == $section_passed['id'] ) {
                ?>
                <p><?php echo $sectiondescription; ?></p>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: Why don't you `extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );` at the beginning of `oenology_hooks_setting_callback()`, so you don't have to save every part of the array into a new `$var`? These will then be avaible with `$'name_inside_the_array`, for ex. '$title`, `$tab`, etc.

Comment: ...because I'm not actually all that smart with PHP? :) I'll give that a try; thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/1006796), which shows some "maybe best practice" example on how to add filters & hooks, parse arguments and deal with query string input. It's a little old and i will likely rework it when i got time, but imo it's worth a look. :)

Comment: This is actually just a Plugin that adds UI for hooks that I've added to Oenology. I'm pretty comfortable with how I've actually *added* the hooks to the Theme. Now, I'm just trying to provide a convenient way to expose them to end users.

Comment: I haven't missunderstood you. I just wanted to show you this in case it might of some help (whenever) to you. I see this code as something ironic - just take a look how much effort it is to get each and everything for everybody in _the wordpress_ way...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you look at the [do_settings_sections](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L1164) function more specifically the line 1164 where the callback function is being executed :

```
call_user_func($section['callback'], $section);
```

you can see that the $section array is being passed to the callback function, so you can identify the callback by the `$section['id']`

hope this make since.

### Update

here is an example, if your add_settings_section callback for all sections was named `oenology_hooks_section_callback` then you can identify it like this:

```
function oenology_hooks_section_callback($section_passed){
    if ($section_passed['id'] == 'whatever_section_id'){
        //do stuff
    }
    if ($section_passed['id'] == 'whatever_section_id_number2'){
        //do other stuff
    }
 }
```

and by do stuff i mean do whatever you want to do with that section callback.

Comment: Hmm... that looks promising. How do I determine `$section['id']`?

Comment: @Chip Bennett `id` will be first argument you pass to `add_settings_section()`

Comment: @Chip Bennett I added an example to try and explain better.

Comment: @Bainternet: Awesome! I have an option script and met the same problem as Chip Bennett has. Now it works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so it finally clicked over the weekend; let me try the code I have in mind, and I'll report back.

Comment: @Bainternet: brilliant! I updated my question with my working code. This is a bit of a coup de grace for me; thank you!

Comment: that was a tricky one :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I'll throw my two cents in, just in case someone else comes along; a simpler way to do so would be do write you own modification of the `add_settings_section()` function, which would only add a callback args parameter at the end of it.

This would look like this ( or something like it )

```
function my_add_settings_section($id, $title, $callback, $page, $callbackargs) {

global $wp_settings_sections;

if ( !isset($wp_settings_sections) ) 
{
    $wp_settings_sections = array();
}

if ( !isset($wp_settings_sections[$page]) )
{
    $wp_settings_sections[$page] = array();
}

if ( !isset($wp_settings_sections[$page][$id]) )
{
    $wp_settings_sections[$page][$id] = array();
}

$wp_settings_sections[$page][$id] = array( 'id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'callback' => $callback, 'callbackargs' => $callbackargs, 'page' => 'page' );
}
```

Now you would simply use this instead of the native wordpress function and access your callback args through the `'callbackargs'` array key in a usual fashion, like this

```
function oenology_hooks_sections_callback( $section_passed ) {
   // Our callback arguments  
   $section_passed['callbackargs']
}
```

Which we could use to pass to some other function :

```
 function oenology_hooks_sections_callback( $section_passed ) {
   // Our callback arguments  
   $args = $section_passed['callbackargs'];
   some_other_function( $args );
}
```

Or the callback args could be an array themselves which we use :

```
function oenology_hooks_sections_callback( $section_passed ) {
   // Our callback arguments  
   if ( $section_passed['callbackargs']['stuff'] !== 'things' ) 
   {
       echo 'stuff is not things!";
   }
}
```

This is all possible because all `add_settings_section()` does is add a new array member to the `$wp_settings_sections` global variable, that new array member could be an array itself containing any number of keys with different names, which could be used, by any function that knew they were there. 
When `do_settings_sections` calls the `call_user_func_array` it passes a `$sections` paramater as Bainternet noted, this means that the entire array we added to `$wp_settings_sections` in `my_add_settings_section()` is passed into our callback, meaning we have access to every new array member we add to it such as the `callbackargs` allowing our function to have a full fledged callback.

Even though im sure that this might be obvious i thought that I'd just explain it in case someone who gets confused looks in.

Answer (score 2):

You can also always use a more general approach, not looking for the particular function implementation (meaning, without checking if add_settings_section passes anything implicitly). This general approach uses PHP closure.

How to use it: in every place, where you pass a function name, instead of it pass an anonymous function, with **use** in it.

Example:

instead of

```
foreach ( $ar as $name => value ) {
    add_settings_section(
        $section,
        'something',
        'something-else',
        'callback_name'
    );
}

function callback_name() {
    do_something();
}
```

you can use:

```
foreach ( $ar as $name => value ) {
    add_settings_section(
        $section,
        'something',
        'something-else',
        function () use ( $name, $value ) {
            callback_name( $name, $value )
        }
    );
}

function callback_name( $name, $value ) {
    do_something( $name, $value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since WordPress 6.1.0, the `add_settings_section()` function now officially has an `$args` parameter. Although the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_section/) does not state it, you can actually use it to pass arguments to the callback function. For example:

```php
add_settings_section('wpse19156_settings_section', 'Section', 'wpse19156_settings_section_callback', 'wpse19156_settings', [
    'description' => '<p>A description, for example.</p>'
]);
```

and

```php
public function wpse19156_settings_section_callback($args) {
    printf('<p>%s</p>', $args['description']);
}
```